# How to collect statistics from firebase dynamic links created manually?

Tags: firebase, usage-statistics, firebase-dynamic-links

I've created dynamic link manually and I would like to collect statistics for it in firebase console.

Is it possible?

Link that I've created contains:

`link`, `apn`, `utm_source` ,`utm_medium`

Comment: The documentation suggests that you use Firebase Analytics to track your dynamic links.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Comment: What stats would you like to collect?

Comment: @theblindprophet link clicks

Comment: @DougStevenson Your comment should be fully fledged answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to shorten the Dynamic Links, for the Firebase console to track clicks for you. From [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android):

> To help you gauge the effectiveness of your promotions and campaigns, the following Analytics events are automatically logged when you open a short Dynamic Link in your app. You can create short Dynamic Links in the Firebase console.

For your existing manually created dynamic link, go to the Console, click on Dynamic Links, then New Dynamic Link. Select Shorten an Existing Dynamic Link, then paste your existing link there, then click the Create Link button.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to create those manually since target URL will change

Comment: Yeah, if you have a lot of dynamically created URLs, having to shorten each one in the Console isn't scalable. Hopefully, there will be a way in the future to shorten them programmatically. In the meantime, you'll have to roll your own click tracking.